# My Carousel only displays the first thing from the database but wont display the next one and onward

Tags: php

My Carousel only displays the first thing from the database but wont display the next one and onward

this is my code and the query
it wont display the 2nd image
but it displays the 1st image 
can anybody help thanks

```
    <?php
            require_once("db2.php");
            $GardenDBB = new GardenDBB();
            $result = ($GardenDBB->LoadAllGallery());
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $counter = 1;
while($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 ?>

<div class="item<?php if ($counter <= 1){echo " active"; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo './upload2/'.$db_field['image_name']?>")>;
<?php
          echo      '<div class="container">';
                  echo  '<div class="row slide-margin">';
                        echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                            echo '<div class="carousel-content">';


                               echo '<h1 class="animation animated-item-1">'.$db_field['proName'].'</h1>';
                               echo '<h2 class="animation animated-item-2">'.$db_field['proDescription'].'</h2>';



                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';

                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
           echo '</div>';

            $counter++;
            }
}

  ?>  



  public function LoadAllGallery() {
    $db_found = $this->connect_Db();
    if ($db_found) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_car";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);            
        return $result;
        mysql_free_result($result);     
    }
    else {
        $errorMsg = "Database NOT Found, Please connect your administrator ";           
    }       
    $this->close_DB();  
}
```

Comment: if ($counter <= 1) is only true the first time through. And all the display code is within that IF.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
if ($counter <= 1)
{
// DIV CLASS="ITEM" wrapper starts here
}

//all the rest of the display code

if ($counter <= 1)
{
echo '</div>'; // DIV CLASS="ITEM" end of wrapper
}
$counter++;
```